# Default group for user when creating files and directories

Tags: permissions, cron, users, groups

I have user `deployment` whos default group is set up to `www-data`. He also belongs to group `xxxxx`.

Then I have a cron script under the user deployment which runs `php script` which generate some dynamic files. This files have set up wrong group `xxxxx` while I want to have `www-data` group for them. I thought that files generated under the user will have set up his default group.

What should I do to force him to set up group I want to set?

Comment: In the output of `groups deployment`, do you see the `www-data` group listed first? ... Have you just changed the primary group for that user and haven't logged out/rebooted yet since then?

Comment: Yes www-data is first group in the list for deployment user

Comment: Yes I changed default group but did not logged out.

Comment: Dont know how but is seems after log out it works.

Comment: I added an answer to explain how/why ... I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Groups are set up by `login` (which is why logout/login works) or by the `newgrp` command (for a single process). Read `man login newgrp chgrp`. Couldn't you simply `chgrp www-data _files_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have changed your user's primary group and hadn't logged out and back in yet.

The change to your user's primary group will not take effect under your user's current logged in session, but will take effect the next time you login with this user.

The current [kernel's user credentials](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/security/credentials.html) are not changed on-the-fly ... They are updated on new logins only(*temporarily changing identity with `su` or `sudo` is considered a new login*).

The main reason for that is that **a user session** is in fact made possible by and actually is a group of running processes that were(*and must be*) created when the user logged in and like everything else(*security-wise*) these processes need credentials to run and do their jobs so they inherit them from the user ... You can see how they look with for example:

```
ps x -o user,group,pid,command
```

Therefor, after changing the credentials for a logged in user, you need to end the current user session by logging out then logging in again so that the user processes under the new session will run with the new credentials.

Comment: Thank you it works.