# How to add user to sudoers really?

Tags: sudo

Ubuntu 20.04.
I have created 2nd user and try to do:

> sudo su
> [sudo] password for xoleg:
> xoleg is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
> xoleg@oleg-HP-2004:~$

Then my other user added this 2nd user

```
>usermod -aG sudo xoleg
```

and yet this

```
>nano /etc/sudoers

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# added this
username ALl=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/mkdir,/bin/rmdir
```

after it again to xoleg session

```
>sudo su
[sudo] password for xoleg: 
xoleg is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Where am I wrong? how to fix it?

Comment: Have you logged out and back in after adding the user to the group?

Comment: No, should this new added user logout/login?

Comment: Yes, ... Please see https://askubuntu.com/a/1468587

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04. To get sudo access, switch to root first using:

```
su root
```

Enter your password when prompted, and then add user to sudo:

```
adduser username sudo
```

Enter your user name in place of username above, now switch back to current user again:

```
su username
```

That's all. Try to run sudo again with your user. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Once you do the `su` and `adduser` just have the user log out and log in again, it'll solve the `sudo` problem.  Because that's the proper way to refresh perms.

Comment: Yes, that also works. But if someone does not want to logout and login again then just `su username` works fine.

Comment: That's disadvised, until you exit out of `su root` because then you can just run `exit` and end up at a root prompt again.  It's *extremely* insecure, so you need to make sure the user exits *after* they are done with root, then they can run `su username` and enter their password otherwise they're in a `root` prompt easily via the execution trees and you *do not* want users to stay in root prompts.